# Model only responds if Windows Service is specified

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django, python-2.7

In my `views.py`, I'm passing a model object through ajax through template. It doesn't respond, but it does if service is mentioned. Can anyone tell me why?

**views.py**:

```py
def serv(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.is_ajax():
            pythoncom.CoInitialize()
            service = request.POST.get('service')
            service_name = request.POST.get('service_name')

        # THIS "service_name" IS NOT GETTING RECOGNIZED BY WMI FUNCTION

            if service == 'stop':
                from socket import *
                c = wmi.WMI()
                for service in c.Win32_Service(Name=service_name):
                    result, = service.StopService()
                numb = 'Service stopped'
                data = {"status": numb}
                return JsonResponse(data)

            if service == 'start':
                from socket import *
                c = wmi.WMI()
                for service in c.Win32_Service(Name=service_name):
                    result, = service.StartService()
                numb = 'Service started'
                data = {"status": numb}
                return JsonResponse(data)

           pythoncom.CoUninitialize()

    return render(request,'django/index.html')
```

**template code**:

```html
{% if category %}
    {% if pages %}
        {% for page in pages %}
            <div class="form-group">
                <form method="POST">
                    {% csrf_token %} 
                    <h4>{{ page.title }}</h4>
                    <div class="col-xs-4">
                        <select class="form-control" id="{{ page.service }}" name="service">
                            <option id="start" value="start">start</option>
                            <option id="stop" value="stop">Stop</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="{{ page.title }}" type="submit">Execute</button>
                    <span id="{{ page.result }}" class="label label-default"></span>
                </form>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}

        </ul>
    {% else %}
        <strong>No pages currently in category.</strong>
    {% endif %}
{% else %}
    The specified category {{ category_name }} does not exist!
{% endif %}
</br>
{% if category %}
     <a class="btn btn-default" href="/rango/category/{{ category_name_slug }}/add_page/">Add a New Service</a><br />
{% else %}
    A category by this name does not exist
{% endif %}
```

**Javascript**:

```js
function getCookie(name) {
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}

//For doing AJAX post
$("#{{ page.title }}").click(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
    var service = $("#{{ page.service }}").val();
    var service_name = $("#{{ page.title }}").val();

    $.ajax({
        url: '{{ page.url }}', // the endpoint,commonly same url
        type: "POST", // http method
        data: {
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrftoken,
            service: service,
            service_name: service_name
        }, // data sent with the post request

        // handle a successful response
        success: function(json) {
            console.log(json); // another sanity check
            //On success show the data posted to server as a message
            $("#{{ page.result }}").append( 'Response:' + json.status);
        },

        // handle a non-successful response
        error: function(xhr, errmsg, err) {
            console.log(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText); // provide a bit more info about the error to the console
        }
    });
});
```

The code works properly if the name of the windows service (which is being controlled here) is specifically mentioned in the

```
for service in c.Win32_Service(Name="bthserv"): //Just an example of what works
```

Comment: What value does `service_name` have when you post a request?

Comment: The value for service name is picked up from Page model,                     var service_name = $("#{{ page.title }}").val();

Comment: If that were true you wouldn't have the error, so when you set a breakpoint in your view, what value does `service_name` show?

Comment: Where does your js code live exactly ? In the template or in a distinct js file ? In the first case, where exactly in the template ? And in both cases, what do you expect something like "$("#{{ page.title }}")" to eval to ?

Comment: I checked it correctly now, when it is passed, service_name shows blank, while service (which is another variable passed for start/stop(not from model) is getting displayed. Any clue why ?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers JS lives in template, after the </form> </div> and before the {% endfor %}. And i expect "$("#{{ page.title }}")" to eval to the title of the page (Page is a model), for any service when start/stop is executed the same view code should be executed, this is what actually i want (making it dynamic so that i dont reapeat code for every new service added), 'Title' field of 'Page Model' contains windows service names.

Comment: Ok that makes more sense... even if you could get the same result with a (css) class instead of an `id` and without repeating the same js code for each and every page but that's another problem.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Hi again, in the same template, after ending the for loop and if else, i've begun with a new {% if category %} same form with new id's, script containing similar AJAX post request taking data from Category.Model {% else %} {% endif %}. Here in this scenario as well the data is not getting passed to the view, any solution ? Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance :)

Comment: Normal data is getting posted, but actually this time i'm passing long URL's with many symbols, it would require me to encode that using some method, encodeURIComponent doesn't work here.. !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want

```
 var service_name = $("#{{ page.title }}").get(0).id;
```

Which is actually a very convoluted way to write:

```
var service_name = "{{ page.title }}";
```